# "Zu/mit einem Mischverhältnis von x vermischt"

Tags: preposition

Welche der beiden Optionen ist korrekt?

> 1. X und Y werden *zu* einem Mischverhältnis von 7:4 vermischt
> 2. X und Y werden *mit* einem Mischverhältnis von 7:4 vermischt

Einerseits wird es so vermischt, dass am Ende ein Mischverhältnis von 7:4 vorliegt. Andererseits kann man es auch so auslegen, dass beide Stoffe *mit* einem bestimmten Verhältnis vermischt werden. Letzteres ist meiner Meinung nach die richtige Option, da das Verhältnis schon vor dem Mischvorgang 7:4 ist.
Liege ich hier richtig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substanzen werden *in* einem bestimmten Verhältnis *ge*mischt (oder *miteinander ver*mischt).

> X und Y werden *in* einem Verhältnis von 7:4 *ge*mischt.
>
> X und Y werden *in* einem Verhältnis von 7:4 *miteinander ver*mischt.

<sup>(Statt *Mischverhältnis* habe ich *Verhältnis* geschrieben, um den [Pleonasmus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmus) „im *Misch*verhältnis *mischen*“ zu umgehen.)</sup>

Man kann auch schreiben:

> X wird *mit* Y *in* einem Verhältnis von 7:4 *ver*mischt.
>
> X wird Y *in* einem Verhältnis von 7:4 *hinzu*gemischt.
>
> X wird Y *in* einem Verhältnis von 7:4 *bei*gemischt.

Trotzdem bleibt es in der Wortfolge „*in* einem Verhältnis“ bei der Präposition *in*. Allerdings ist in den letzten Beispielen nur noch X Subjekt des Satzes, wodurch Substanz X wichtiger erscheint als Substanz Y. Das ist aber nur eine Bedeutungsnuance.

Für die Präposition *zu* fällt mir kein sinnvolles Beispiel ein.

Comment: Interessant, vielen Dank.

Comment: Wenn _»zu«_, dann z. B. so: _»X und Y werden im Verhältnis von 7:4 zu einem Saft vermischt._«

Comment: @Pollitzer Stimmt :-)

Comment: X wird zu Y beigemischt.

Comment: @raznagul, das Verb *beimischen* wird standardsprachlich ohne *zu* gebraucht. Vgl. das von mir hinzugefügte Beispiel.